# What is the best 3D modeling and design program?

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d

Hey i would love to get into 3D modeling and design and i was wondering if their were any alternatives to 3DS Max and other such programs for Ubuntu

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## [Blender](http://www.blender.org) [image: install blender]

[image: blender]

Blender is the best free and open source 3D modelling program out there by a long shot!

The program is under constant development, has a huge community and has been used in many major films for video editing and 3D concepts. As Said before blender has new builds being uploaded hourly at [graphicall.org](http://graphicall.org) and you can download all the official stable, aplha and beta versions of the program at [belnder.org](http://www.blender.org/).

The community is friendly and welcoming and you can fit right in at sites suchs as [blenderartist.org](http://blenderartist.org), [blendernation](http://www.blendernation.com/) and [blenderguru](http://www.blenderguru.com/) (great website for tutorials.
I myself have been using the program for about six years now, and have used it for both personal and commercial projects: These can be seen at ([sixthlaw3d.wordpress.com](http://sixthlaw3d.wordpress.com)).

To see the quality of what can be produced using blender, watch [Elephants Dream](http://www.elephantsdream.org/), [Big Buck Bunny](http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/) and [Sintel](http://www.sintel.org/). All were created using blender, and other free software on Ubuntu.

The program has a brilliant set of tools, and the development team are constantly making improvements on the software to keep it cutting edge and competitive.
This is a very, very short summary of this awesome program but check out it in more detail in the above links :)

Happy blendering!:)

Comment: thanks man  by the way the stuff at www.sixthlaw3d.wordpress.com looks amazing and its really helpful!

Comment: http://cg.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/blender/ is nice too

Comment: I highly recommend trying out the 2.5 version (still in beta though). Historically Blender has been criticised for it's very difficult user interface - and that's been changed in the 2.5 version. So if you're going to put any effort into learning Blender, spend that energy on the new User Interface paradigm.